# Linux - Script to edit clipboard content

Tags: linux, clipboard, gentoo

Is there a way to write a script that would be applied to the clipboard content ( I'm using Linux\Gentoo)?

When copy-pasting it would be nice to bind a keystroke that would (e.g -) remove all line breaks from the copied text.

I couldn't find where to start such a task (where should such a script be placed\how to reference the clipboard) so just a hint of where to start would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `xsel` to access your clipboard.  Then you can just use a small script and piping.  I use this to prepend four spaces to my current selection in order to get a version I can paste into StackOverflow editors:

```
xsel | while IFS='' read a; do echo "    $a"; done | xsel
```

Default for `xsel` is to manipulate (or query) your PRIMARY selection (what you just marked with the mouse).  You can use the clipboard (C-c, C-v stuff) instead by using the option `-b`.

To remove all line breaks from your current clipboard, just try this:

```
xsel -b | tr '\n' '\r' | sed 's/\r*//g' | xsel -b
```